# How can I start foreach command from specific moment?

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I use XML import for my website. The main problem is the execution time and the limit enforced by my server. Because of that I want to split XML import into segments. My script looks so far in this way:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

foreach ($xml->products as $products) {

...

}
```

The question is how can I start **foreach** command from specific moment, e.g. foreach could start from 100. I know it can be done in this way below, but is there any easier way?

```
$n=0;
foreach ($xml->products as $products) {
$n++;
if ($n>99) { //do something }
else { //skip }

}
```

Comment: check Generators in PHP 5.5 [click here](http://sheriframadan.com/2012/10/test-drive-php-5-5-a-sneak-peek/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a for loop, than you can specify the range you want to loop over

```
for($i = 100; $i < 200; $i++)
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: This is nice idea, from 100 to 200, but I want from 100 to the end of all values in $xml->products. So there is a way to get know how many values has $xml->products? Because for example if $xml->products ends at 110 then 90 times will be loop empty.

Comment: yup you can, make it `for($i=100; $i < count($xml->products); $i++)`

Comment: Thanks @Naryl - now the answer is complete. It is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with a `for` or a `while` like other people suggested or you can use `continue` if it MUST be a `foreach`:

```
$n=0; //you have to do this outside or it won't work at all.
$min_value=100;
foreach ($xml->products as $products) {
    $n++;
    if ($n<=$min_value) { continue; } //this will exit the current iteration, check the bool in the foreach and start the next iteration if the bool is true. You don't need a else here.

    //do the rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea, "continue" command can be useful for me later. I think "for" with "count" as you mentioned before can be better for my php script.

Comment: `continue` is usually more usefull when you want to skip specific elements following other criteria that their order, for example ones that have a id equal to a value, or have a null element, etc.